# Apache Daemon jvm mode not work with PC installed JDK

Tags: java, apache, service, daemon

As following:

```
set APP_HOME=%~dp0

"%APP_HOME%\prunsrv.exe" //IS//MyService--DisplayName "MyService" --Description "Some description" --Install "%APP_HOME%prunsrv.exe"
--Jvm="%APP_HOME%..\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll" ^
                --StartMode=exe --Startup=auto --StartImage="%APP_HOME%\Start.exe" ^
                --StopMode=jvm --StopClass=com.StopClass --StopMethod=stop ^
                --LogPath "%APP_HOME%logs" --StdOutput auto --StdError auto --LogLevel Debug
```

Starting service with exe mode is OK. But, When I stop the service, something wrong, log show:

```
[2016-05-08 18:30:49] [debug] ( prunsrv.c:1679) [10092] Commons Daemon procrun log initialized
[2016-05-08 18:30:49] [info]  ( prunsrv.c:1683) [10092] Commons Daemon procrun (1.0.15.0 64-bit) started
[2016-05-08 18:30:49] [info]  ( prunsrv.c:687 ) [10092] Stopping service 'MyService' ...
[2016-05-08 18:30:49] [debug] ( prunsrv.c:844 ) [ 9164] reportServiceStatusE: 3, 0, 3000, 0
[2016-05-08 18:30:49] [info]  ( prunsrv.c:943 ) [ 3324] Stopping service...
[2016-05-08 18:30:49] [debug] ( javajni.c:233 ) [ 3324] loading jvm 'E:\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll'
[2016-05-08 18:30:49] [debug] ( javajni.c:278 ) [ 3324] Setting DLL search path to 'E:\jre\bin\server'
[2016-05-08 18:30:49] [debug] ( javajni.c:278 ) [ 3324] Setting DLL search path to 'E:\jre\bin'
[2016-05-08 18:30:49] [error] ( javajni.c:291 ) [ 3324] %1 不是有效的 Win32 应用程序。
[2016-05-08 18:30:49] [error] ( prunsrv.c:958 ) [ 3324] Failed creating java E:\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
[2016-05-08 18:30:49] [error] ( prunsrv.c:958 ) [ 3324] %1 不是有效的 Win32 应用程序。
[2016-05-08 18:30:53] [error] ( prunsrv.c:708 ) [10092] Failed to stop 'MyService' service
[2016-05-08 18:30:54] [error] ( prunsrv.c:708 ) [10092] 传递给系统调用的数据区域太小。
[2016-05-08 18:30:54] [info]  ( prunsrv.c:716 ) [10092] Stop service finished.
[2016-05-08 18:30:54] [error] ( prunsrv.c:1755) [10092] Commons Daemon procrun failed with exit value: 6 (Failed to stop service)
[2016-05-08 18:30:54] [error] ( prunsrv.c:1755) [10092] 传递给系统调用的数据区域太小。
```

What really confusing me is that the same thing under the system with no jdk installed is OK, everything goes well!

So, does the installed JDK will influence my specify Jvm ???

This is really depressed me... Thank you very much for any help.